# mysql LOAD DATA FILE can't able to access unix shell variables

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am using **MYSQL LOAD DATA** utility to load data. I moved whole commands to a control file for simplicity. The path for input file, i kept in one **SHELL VARIABLE** called **C_PATH** and i exported too in **UNIX**. But **MySQL** can't able to access the path for that file as it's not able to interpret environment variable value.

below is the command and contents for Ctrl file.

> mysql -uuser -ppwd -hhost_name schema_name -e "$(cat /home/jboss/maria_test_YYYYMMDD/IXQDWFIS.ctl)"

`/home/jboss/maria_test_YYYYMMDD/hello.ctl)` contents are as  below:

---

```
   load data
     LOCAL INFILE `'$C_PATH/hello.uld'`

     into table IXQDWFIS
     CHARACTER SET UTF8
     fields terminated by '~'
       LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
     (EMP_NO,
        EMP_NAME
      )
```

### ERROR:

> ERROR 2 (HY000) at line 1: File '$C_PATH/hello.uld'

Comment: Use double quote. With single quote the $ sign is just dollar sign, not variable prefix

Comment: @Tamar, I tried your suggestion, getting below error   "ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"$C_PATH/hello.uld"

into table EMP
CHARACTER SET UTF8
fields te' at line 2
"

Comment: You cat the content of the file, if you want it to be evaluate you have to run it.

Comment: The double-quote fix did not work because that led to nested double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the code instead of printing it:

```
mysql -uuser -ppwd -hhost_name schema_name \
   -e "$(echo `cat /home/jboss/maria_test_YYYYMMDD/IXQDWFIS.ctl`)
```

Comment: hi @Tamar, not worked above either. Tried below one, working fine. Thanks for your input. mysql -uuser -ppwd -hhost_name schema_name   -e "$( echo $(</home/jboss/maria_test_YYYYMMDD/IXQDWFIS.ctl) | sed  "s|\$C_PATH|$C_PATH|" )"

Answer (score 0):

not worked above either. Tried below one, working fine. Thanks for your input.

```
mysql -uuser -ppwd -hhost_name schema_name -e "$( echo $(</home/jboss/maria_test_YYYYMMDD/IXQDWFIS.ctl) | sed "s|\$C_PATH|$C_PATH|" )"
```